# Synchronous calls in two nested loops

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I have Synchronous calls in two nested 'for' loops in Node.JS: Here is my Asynchronous call; I don't know how I can have synchronous version of my code, which goes to next iteration when create_db is done!

```
    var new_items = [];
    for (var key in config.models) {
       var selected_field = config.models[key];
       for (var item in config.models[key].fields) {
          var selected_item = config.models[key].fields[item];
          new_items.push({AttributeName: selected_item.name, AttributeType: selected_item.type});     
       }
       CreateDB(selected_field.name, new_items);       
       var selected_item = config.models[key].fields[item];

   }
```

EDDITED: In create_db I'm using call back function!

```
function CreateDB(name, new_items) {

ddb.createTable(name, {hash: ['id', ddb.schemaTypes().number],
    range: ['time', ddb.schemaTypes().string],
    AttributeDefinitions: new_items
},
{read: 1, write: 1}, function(err, details) {
    console.log("The DB is now created!");
});
```

}

Thanks

Comment: uhm. you only have one function call, and it isn't inside the nested loop. What exactly is the problem? if create_db is asynchronous and can't be modified to be synchronous, and doesn't implement a promise interface and doesn't have a callback, there is no solution to your problem.

Comment: I dont see any asynchronous calls in your code. The only issue is you declared the same variable twice selected_item

Comment: EDDITED: In create_db I'm using call back function!

Comment: Then you'll need a recursive function, or something like the async module.

Comment: Thanks @KevinB I have included my CreateDB function as well! Recursive is simple for one loop, is it possible for two nested loops as well?

Comment: @dbrin  Sorry I forgot to mention my CreateDB, where I used a callback. I was wondering if I can change my function to a recursive one with my  (my foreach logic)! I have added CreateDB in my post now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to modify your `CreateDB` function so that it takes a callback and then call that callback in `.createTable`s callback:

```
function CreateDB(name, new_items, callback) {
    ddb.createTable(name, {hash: ['id', ddb.schemaTypes().number],
        range: ['time', ddb.schemaTypes().string],
        AttributeDefinitions: new_items
    },
    {read: 1, write: 1}, function(err, details) {
        console.log("The DB is now created!");
        callback(err, details);
    });
}
```

Then you can use something like the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module's [each method](https://github.com/caolan/async#each).  Something like:

```
var async = require('async');

async.each(Object.keys(config.models), function(key, callback) {
   var new_items = [];
   var selected_field = config.models[key];
   for (var item in config.models[key].fields) {
      var selected_item = config.models[key].fields[item];
      new_items.push({AttributeName: selected_item.name, AttributeType: selected_item.type});     
   }
   CreateDB(selected_field.name, new_items, callback);
}, function(err) {
    // All done with CreateDB calls
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution; I just couldn't understand the logic you used for "callback" in async.each! I saw the documentation (https://github.com/caolan/async#each) and they are assigning callback to the result, but you are not! could you please explain it further?

Comment: Are you assigning the "callback" in async.each with whatever it returns in create_db? Thanks

Comment: Yes, essentially `callback` gets called with the results of `CreateDB`.  `callback` is being passed from `async.each` directly to `CreateDB` as the last parameter here: `CreateDB(selected_field.name, new_items, callback);`.  `CreateDB` then calls it directly when it's done. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `async` module. It has utility functions that make what I *think* you're trying to do really easy.

```
async.each(Object.keys(config.models), function(key, done) {
    var selected_field = config.models[key];

    // I used the 'map' function to make it a bit easier to read
    var new_items = selected_field.fields.map(function(item) {
        return {
            AttributeName: item.name
            AttributeType: item.type
        };
    });

    CreateDB(selected_field, new_items, done);

}, function(err) {
    // this gets called when all db calls are finished
    console.log("The DB is now created!");
});

function CreateDB(name, new_items, callback) {
    ddb.createTable(name, {
        hash: ['id', ddb.schemaTypes().number],
        range: ['time', ddb.schemaTypes().string],
        AttributeDefinitions: new_items
    }, {
        read: 1,
        write: 1
    }, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like [Futures](https://github.com/FuturesJS/) , most especially their sequence code, here : [sequence](https://github.com/FuturesJS/sequence)

Hope this helps!

Edit: I believe you can also use a more built-in approach with es6-promise. However, I have no knowledge on this... :)